# Bootstrap: navbar showing a line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm new in Bootstrap, I wanted to create a vertical menu and I do it, but at bottom of "navbar" there is a black line that I can't find how to delete it, here the code I used:

HTML

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="menu-bar">
        <li><img src="#"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav></div>
```

CSS

```
    #menu-bar .panel {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -box-shadow: none;
}

#navbar {
    margin-left: 10%;
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    background-image: url(../images/backnav.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-color: transparent;
    }
```

Did you have any suggestion to fix this?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the "navbar-inverse" class. Here is a fiddle: 
http://www.bootply.com/124086

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<nav>
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked" id="menu-bar">
        <li><img src="#"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>
```